# jquery get parent of child having text

Tags: jquery, selector

I am using jQuery UI dialog widget.  I am creating two buttons "Start/Cancel".  I need to write some code that causes the Start button to be clicked.  jQuery UI creates the following markup:

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Start</span></button>
```

So, basically, I would like a selector that selects the parent element (button) based on the child element's (span) text ("Start").  Is there a selector that can accomplish that?

Thanks,
Jerome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, not tested..

```
$("button > span:contains('Start')").parent().click();
```

Comment: You answer definitely gets me a reference to the button.  Sadly, however, the "click()" portion doesn't cause the function I pass into the $.dialog() to be triggered.  But that's not a problem with your selector, just a vagary of the dialog widget, I imagine.  Thanks for the help!